# Problem solving a minimization problem in cvxpy

Tags: python, solver, cvxpy

I have a linear optimization problem, which can be expressed in a cost function code like this:

```
value_to_minimize = 0.0;
for i in range(0, len(v_1)):
    value_to_minimize += np.abs(v_1[i] - (v_2[i] * c1 + v_3[i] * c2 + v_4[i] * c3));
```

The task of the solver should be to find values for the variables `c1`, `c2`, `c3` which minimize the value.  As boundary conditions, `c1`, `c2`, `c3` together should result in 1.0 and not be negative.
`v_1`, `v_2`, `v_3` and `v_4` are vectors with 10000 float values.

Here is the outline to solve this minimization problem in cvxpy, but without the parameter pass in cp.Minimize(...):

```
V1 = np.array(v_1).reshape(10000, 1)
V2 = np.array(v_2 + v_3 + v_4).reshape(10000, 3)
c = cp.Variable((3,1),nonneg=True)

prob = cp.Problem(cp.Minimize(..., # ???
                [sum(c) == 1])) 
prob.solve(verbose=True)
```

How would the minimize function for cvxpy look in that case?

Comment: (1) what values are wrong and in what way? (2) make sure things can be reproduced.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen Thanks for your reply. The three values in the `c` Variable do not contain the optimal values, because I can find better values with trial and error. Reproducibility is not so easy to achieve in this case, an estimation whether `cp.pnorm(u - cp.sum(V@c), 1))` really does what I want would help me.

Comment: Without a small piece of code that reproduces the problem (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), I am not sure how I can help.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen Thank you very much. I have now edited the question to make it more open.

Comment: BTW. Why do you want to use this particular library? This seems like a relatively simple linear optimization problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't mind using another library, I would recommend `scipy` for this one:

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize
import numpy as np

def OF(x0, v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4):
  value_to_minimize = 0.0
  for i in range(0, len(v_1)):
    value_to_minimize += np.abs(v_1[i] - (v_2[i] * x0[0] + v_3[i] * x0[1] + v_4[i] * x0[2]))
  return value_to_minimize


if __name__ == '__main__':

  x0 = np.array([0, 0, 0])
  v_1 = np.random.randint(10, size = 10000)
  v_2 = np.random.randint(10, size = 10000)
  v_3 = np.random.randint(10, size = 10000)
  v_4 = np.random.randint(10, size = 10000)


  minx0 = np.repeat(0, [len(x0)] , axis = 0)
  maxx0 = np.repeat(np.inf, [len(x0)] , axis = 0)
  bounds = tuple(zip(minx0, maxx0))

  cons = {'type':'eq', 
  'fun':lambda x0: 1 - sum(x0)}
  res_cons = minimize(OF, x0, (v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4), bounds = bounds, constraints=cons, method='SLSQP')



  print(res_cons)
  print('Current value of objective function: ' + str(res_cons['fun']))
  print('Current value of controls:')
  print(res_cons['x'])
```

Output is:

```
     fun: 27919.666908810435
     jac: array([5092.        , 5672.        , 5108.39868164])
 message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
    nfev: 126
     nit: 21
    njev: 21
  status: 0
 success: True
       x: array([0.33333287, 0.33333368, 0.33333345])
Current value of objective function: 27919.666908810435
Current value of controls:
[0.33333287 0.33333368 0.33333345]
```

But obviously the actual values here do not mean much since I just used random integers for the `v_` values... just a demo that this model would meet your constraint of `c` values adding to 1 and boundary of not less than zero (negative).

**edit update:** did not look at the OF/constraints closely enough to realize this was a linear problem... should be using a linear solver algorithm (though, you can use a nonlinear, it's overkill though).

`scipy`'s linear solvers are not great for complex optimization problems like this one, reverting back to `cvxpy` :

```
import numpy as np
import cvxpy as cp

# Create two scalar optimization variables.
x = cp.Variable()
y = cp.Variable()
z = cp.Variable()

v_1 = np.random.randint(10, size = 10000)
v_2 = np.random.randint(10, size = 10000)
v_3 = np.random.randint(10, size = 10000)
v_4 = np.random.randint(10, size = 10000)

constraints = [x + y + z == 1, x >= 0, y >= 0, z >= 0]

objective = cp.Minimize(cp.sum(cp.abs(v_1 - (v_2 * x + v_3 * y + v_4 * z))))

prob = cp.Problem(objective, constraints)
print("Value of OF:", prob.solve())
print('Current value of controls:')
print(x.value, y.value, z.value)
```

output:

```
Value of OF: 27621.999978414093
Current value of controls:
0.3333333333016109 0.33333333406414983 0.3333333326298208
```

Comment: Many thanks for the solution, which works perfectly. However, I have seen that the SLSQP is a non-linear solver, whereas my problem has a linear state space. Could I be criticized for this in a scientific paper?

Comment: @MerklT ah I didn't read your function, yea you should be using a linear solver for a linear problem.. you wouldn't be criticized for SLSQP.. but you might get some looks since its kinda overkill. I posted an update !

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend removing one of the parameters and a constraint. If you know that `c1 + c2 + c3 = 1.`, then use `c3 = 1. - c1 - c2`! This makes the task of minimizer much easier. Also if `v_1` etc. are numpy arrays, then use them as arrays, e.g.,

```py
c3 = 1. - c1 - c2
value_to_minimize = np.sum(np.abs(v_1 - (v_2 * c1 + v_3 * c2 + v_4 * c3)))
```

Comment: The simplification of c3 seems logical, thank you for that. How would you solve the minimization problem? With another library?